# How I can each number to be on one side of the radar chart?

Tags: r, shiny, radar-chart

I'm trying to plot a radar chart in r shiny, but But the chart draws the average scores.

How I can attach names to  `scores()`  ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library("DT")
library(ECharts2Shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    table <- "responses", 
    titlePanel("Wheel of life"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      
      sidebarPanel(
        
        sliderInput("jesm1", "Q1",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("jesm2", "Q2",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("ravabet1", "Q3",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("ravabet2", "Q4",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("job1", "Q5",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("job2", "Q6",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("mali1", "Q7",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("mali2", "Q8",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("enter1", "Q9",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        sliderInput("enter2", "Q10",
                    min = 1, max = 5,
                    value = 1),
        
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
        
        
      ),
      
      mainPanel(
        
        tableOutput("values"),
      #  plotOutput("pe"),
        loadEChartsLibrary(),
        tags$div(id="test", style="width:100%;height:400px;"),
        deliverChart(div_id = "test"),
        textOutput("he")
      ))
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sliderValues <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Name = c("jesmani",
               "ravabet",
               "job",
               "mail",
               "enter"),
      
      Value = as.character(c((input$jesm1 + input$jesm2)/2,
                             
                             (input$ravabet1 +  input$ravabet2)/2,
                             
                             (input$job1 +  input$job2)/2,
                             
                             (input$mali1 +  input$mali2)/2,
                             
                             (input$enter1 + input$enter2)/2)))
    
  })
  
  scores <- reactive({
    data.frame((c((input$jesm1 + input$jesm2)/2,
                (input$ravabet1 +  input$ravabet2)/2,
                             (input$job1 +  input$job2)/2,
                             (input$mali1 +  input$mali2)/2,
                             (input$enter1 + input$enter2)/2)))
    
  })
  #names(scores) <- c("jesmani","ravabet","job","mail","enter")
  jesmi <- reactive({data.frame(input$jesm1 + input$jesm2)/2})
  ravabet <- reactive({data.frame(input$ravabet1 +input$ravabet2)/2})
  job <- reactive({data.frame(input$job1 +  input$job2)/2})
  mali <- reactive({data.frame(input$mali1 +  input$mali2)/2})
  enter <- reactive({data.frame(input$enter1 + input$enter2)/2})
  

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    output$values <- renderTable({
      sliderValues()
    })
   
  #  output$pe <- renderPlot({
      
      renderRadarChart(div_id = "test", data = scores())
 #   })
    output$he <- renderText({
      'High: Extraverts get their energy from interacting with others, while introverts get their energy from within themselves.
      Extraversion includes the traits of energetic, talkative, and assertive. They enjoy being with people, participating in social gatherings,
      and are full of energy.'
    })
    
    })
  
  
}
    
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks...

Comment: I don't get any error after running your code. What error do you get?

Comment: OK, But I want each number to be on one side of the chart.